# Error on node js socket io?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

My code was correctly but still Error on node js `socket.io`. How do I fix it ?

**app.js**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});

var clients = 0;
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    clients++;
    io.sockets.emit('boardcast', {message: clients + ' clients connected!'});
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        clients--;
        io.sockets.emit('boardcast', {message: clients + ' clients connected!'});
    });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('start server on port :3000');
});
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js"></script>

<script>
var socket = io();
socket.on('broadcast', function(data){
    document.body.innerHTML = '';
    document.write(data.message);
});
</script>

<h1>hello world</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

.

ssh

```
node app.js
```

return value

```
start server on port :3000
express deprecated res.sendfile: Use res.sendFile instead app.js:6:6
```

Comment: You have `boardcast` in one place and `broadcast` in the other.  Not the same spelling.

Comment: Plus `document.write(data.message);` when a socket.io message arrives will clear the current document and write a new one.  That is not what you want to do in the client.  Perhaps you just to do `document.body.innerHTML = data.message`.

Comment: i don't under stand 
------------
Plus document.write(data.message); when a socket.io message arrives will clear the current document and write a new one. That is not what you want to do in the client. Perhaps you just to do document.body.innerHTML = data.message.
---------------
What it's mean sir.

Comment: Have you ever actually done `document.write()` after the document was already loaded?  It will wipe out your current document, including your socket.io connection.  It's NOT how you add things to the current document after the document has been loaded.